# Pass Null Values In A SQL Command (For Two Columns) - Adding In Foreach Loop

Tags: c#, sql-server, multidimensional-array, command, select-query

I want to select rows from my SQL Server table (it has `3` columns) and to display them into my Datagridview. My problem about null values. How can I pass null values? (Sometimes the first column and the second column are empty.
).

Below is my code:

```
    string cm = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM mytablename WHERE column1='" 
   + sIS[mSI] + "' AND column2='" + sR[mSSI] + "' OR column1='" + sR[mSSI] 
   + "' AND column2='" + sIS[mSI] + "'";
```

Note: I edited my code.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using parameters to pass values into a SQL statement or else you will be vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You can create a `SqlCommand` object, create `SqlParameter` objects, then set values on them. If any of your values are null, then you can pass `DBNull.Value` as the parameter value.

```
SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
string cm = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 "
cm += "FROM mytablename "
cm += "WHERE column1=@mSI "
cm += "AND column2=@mSSI OR column1=@mYSI AND column2=@mSI";
cmd.CommandText = cm;

for(int mSSI=0; mSSI<sR.Count(); mSSI++)
{
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mSI ", sR[mSI]);

   // check for a null value
   if (sr[mSSI] == null)
   {
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mSSI", DBNull.Value);
   }
   else
   { 
     cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mSSI", sR[mSSI]);
   }

   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mYSI", sR[mYSI]);

   SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   DataTable dat = new DataTable();
   sd.Fill(dat);
   // clear parameters after each iteration
   cmd.Parameters.Clear()
}
```

Comment: Can I add my values into foreach loop again?

Comment: yes. updated my answer. Since you're creating a new `SqlCommand` object during every iteration, you just re-add them. This of course can be optimized, but the code above will get the job done.

Comment: Should I create SQL commands between of two for loops? It's hard to understand, sorry.

Comment: It doesn't work. "SqlDataAdapter sd = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);" it gives error. (Error Value of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' cannot be converted to 'String')

Comment: fixed. was using wrong constructor. you only need to create the `SqlCommand` once - just clear the parameters after each iteration as I am doing in the sample

Comment: Why we use only one for loop? I need two.

Comment: i only included the relevant part of the code based on your question. your code will produce a `DataTable` for every iteration of the `for` loop. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Yes. But it doesn't work again. Error: "System.InvalidOperationException: ExecuteReader: CommandText property has been not initialized"

Comment: For string cm, why did we just write it once and never use it?

Comment: it needs to be set to the `SqlCommand.CommandText` property as shown in the answer

Comment: I'm trying again sir.

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The variable name '@mSSI' has already been declared. Variable names must be unique within a query batch or stored procedure.'

Comment: do you have the `cmd.Parameters.Clear()` at the end of the loop?

Comment: Yes sir, as your answer.

Comment: You have two loops. You will need to modify the code so the parameters are only being created once per `da.Fill`. That is why you're getting the error

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer to your question is using "DBNull.Value" as mentioned above, something like this;

```
            string cm = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM mytablename WHERE column1='"
           + DBNull.Value + "' AND column2='" + DBNull.Value + "' OR column1='" + sR[mSSI]
           + "' AND column2='" + DBNull.Value + "'";
```

Comment: You used only sR[mSSI], I will not select only for it. I need to select also sIS[mSI]. My command row is; string cm = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM mytablename WHERE column1='" 
       + sIS[mSI] + "' AND column2='" + sR[mSSI] + "' OR column1='" + sR[mSSI] 
       + "' AND column2='" + sIS[mSI] + "'";

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here; I gave that string as an example to show how you can pass "null" values in an SQL command. I was not checking or trying to fix your query. Anyways, a regular select query should bring empty values. I don't think you need a complex "WHERE" condition.

Comment: Sometimes the first column and the second column are empty. How can fix that null values in my "string cm = "SELECT column1, column2, column3 FROM mytablename WHERE column1='" + sIS[mSI] + "' AND column2='" + sR[mSSI] + "' OR column1='" + sR[mSSI] + "' AND column2='" + sIS[mSI] + "'";" row. I think I can't understand to your code, but thank you for answer. By the way, the answers must be complete. Because, I already don't know the correct answer and If you post missing code, I don't understand it sir.